# Best Linq Syntax for Adding Objects of a class to a List of a Base Class

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a list of a base class when the objects inside are of a class which inherits my base class. I am after the quickest syntax for that.

I have the following class

```
public class ObjectA : BaseObject
{
    public string ObjectAName {get;set;}
}
```

and my method is :

```
    private List<BaseObject> GetList()
    {
        List<ObjectA> aList = MyData.ObjectA.FindAll(delegate(ObjectA my) { return my.ObjectAName == "Harold"; });
        List<BaseObject> baseList = new List<BaseObject>();
        foreach(ObjectA obj in aList)
        {
            baseList.Add(obj);
        }
        return baseList;
    }
```

Is there a more direct linq syntax ?

Comment: If you will change return type to `IEnumerable<BaseObject>` then you will be able to return list of ObjectA, because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative if you are creating a new list from an existing list is to use the overloaded list constructor taking an IEnumerable:

```
private List<BaseObject> GetList()
{
    List<ObjectA> aList = MyData.ObjectA.FindAll(delegate(ObjectA my) { return my.ObjectAName == "Harold"; });
    List<BaseObject> baseList = new List<BaseObject>(aList.OfType<BaseObject>());

    return baseList;
}
```

That being said, Its unclear here why you actually need a new list rather than returning a filtered IEnumerable and removing the need for the extra memory pointers in two lists at all. That's what Yield was created for.

Comment: Thanks for answers, there are probably more than one correct but Jim Wooley and Sergey Berezovskiy make the correct point that I should be just returning IEnumerable in cases like these. If I did that there is no need for the second collection at all.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this.

```
baseList.AddRange(MyData.ObjectA.Where(o=>o.ObjectAName == "Harold"));
```

Alternatively you can do this

```
private List<BaseObject> GetList()
{
    return MyData.ObjectA.Where(o=>o.ObjectAName == "Harold").Cast<BaseObject>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
private List<BaseObject> GetList()
{
    return MyData.ObjectA
        .FindAll(my => my.ObjectAName == "Harold")
        .Cast<BaseObject>()
        .ToList();
}
```

Note that [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is simply an instance method of `List<T>` and not part of LINQ.

Comment: That doesn't add them to the new list. It appears to be a duplicate of .Where anyway.

Comment: To compile this, return type should be `IEnumerable<BaseObject>`

Comment: @MehmetAtaş: Thanks, haven't had enough coffee. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

just use      `AddRange`

```
 private List<BaseObject> GetList()
            {
                List<ObjectA> aList = MyData.ObjectA.FindAll(delegate(ObjectA my) { return my.ObjectAName == "Harold"; });
                List<BaseObject> baseList = new List<BaseObject>();
                //foreach (ObjectA obj in aList)
                //{
                //    baseList.Add(obj);
                //}
                baseList.AddRange(aList);
                return baseList;
            }
```